# Error: receive_text_message can not be null in Chats App android studio kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a Chats App. There is a issue with my receiving messages.
When there is no previous Messages, and we are starting from the beginning, user1 can send as many messages he want. But when the user2 tries to open chat with user1, an error occurs saying : "
**java.lang.NullPointerException: itemView.findViewById(R.id.receive_text_message) must not be null**"
I think this is because there is some error in my Messages_Adapter file due to which it is not able to retrieve non-nullable messages.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem?
Thanks in advance.

My Message Adapter Code :

```
package com.example.driftdb

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class MessageAdapter(val context: Context , private val messageList: ArrayList<Messages>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    private val ITEM_R = 0
    private val ITEM_S = 1

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup , viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return if(viewType == 0){
            // inflate receive
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.received_layout,parent,false)
            ReceiveViewHolder(view)
        } else{
            // inflate receive
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.sent_layout,parent,false)
            SentViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder , position: Int) {
        val currentMessage = messageList[position]
        if(holder.javaClass == SentViewHolder::class.java){
            // do the stuff for sent view holder
            val viewHolder = holder as SentViewHolder
            holder.sentMessage.text = currentMessage.message
        }
        else{
            // do the stuff for receive view holder
            val viewHolder = holder as ReceiveViewHolder
            holder.receiveMessage.text = currentMessage.message
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val currentMessage = messageList[position]
        return if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.phoneNumber.equals(currentMessage.senderNumber)){
            ITEM_S
        } else{
            ITEM_R
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messageList.size
    }

    class SentViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val sentMessage: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sent_text_message)
    }
    class ReceiveViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val receiveMessage: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receive_text_message)
        //  *********** THIS IS THE POINT WHERE NULLPOINTER ERROR COMES IN ***********
    }
}
```

My FullChats.kt file where I am sending and receiving messages:

```
package com.example.driftdb


import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.driftdb.databinding.ActivityFullChatsBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*


class FullChats : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityFullChatsBinding
    private lateinit var sendButton: ImageButton
    private lateinit var messageAdapter: MessageAdapter
    private lateinit var messageList: ArrayList<Messages>
    private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private var receiverRoom: String?= null
    private var senderRoom: String?= null
    private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFullChatsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")


        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("sharingChatsData",MODE_PRIVATE)
        val receiverName = sharedPref.getString("userName" , "Error! Not Found").toString()
        val receiverNumber = sharedPref.getString("userPhoneNumber" , "Error! Not Found").toString()
        binding.UserNameButton.text = receiverName



        messageList = ArrayList()
        messageAdapter = MessageAdapter(this@FullChats,messageList)


        binding.personalChatsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.personalChatsRecyclerView.adapter = messageAdapter



        val senderNumber = auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber
        senderRoom = receiverNumber + senderNumber
        receiverRoom = senderNumber + receiverNumber


        Log.i(senderRoom,receiverRoom.toString())

        // logic for adding data to recyclerView
        db.child("All MESSAGES").child(senderRoom.toString()).child("messages").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                messageList.clear()
                for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val msg: Messages? = postSnapshot.getValue(Messages::class.java)
                    messageList.add(msg!!)
                }
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext,"DB ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })


        // adding the message to Database
        binding.sentButton.setOnClickListener{
            val msg = binding.typeMessageText.text.toString()
            if(checkingUserName(msg)){
                val msgObj = Messages(msg,senderNumber)
                db.child("All MESSAGES").child(senderRoom.toString()).child("messages").push().setValue(msgObj).addOnSuccessListener {
                    db.child("All MESSAGES").child(receiverRoom.toString()).child("messages").push().setValue(msgObj)
                }
                binding.typeMessageText.setText("")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkingUserName(userName: String): Boolean {
        val n = userName.length
        var flag = 0
        for(i in 0 until n){
            val c = userName[i]
            if (c != ' ') flag = 1
        }
        return flag == 1
    }
}
```

Edit: Added Messages Model

```
package com.example.driftdb

class Messages {
    var message: String? = null
    var senderNumber: String? = null

    constructor(){}

    constructor(message: String?, senderNumber: String?){
        this.message = message
        this.senderNumber = senderNumber
    }
}
```

UPDATE : ADDED LOGS

```
2022-11-09 21:47:08.742 30144-30144 AndroidRuntime          com.example.driftdb                  D  Shutting down VM
2022-11-09 21:47:08.747 30144-30144 AndroidRuntime          com.example.driftdb                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.driftdb, PID: 30144
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: itemView.findViewById(R.id.receive_text_message) must not be null
                                                                                                        at com.example.driftdb.MessageAdapter$ReceiveViewHolder.<init>(MessageAdapter.kt:59)
                                                                                                        at com.example.driftdb.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.kt:24)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
                                                                                                        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7020)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7020)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:496)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7020)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7020)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7020)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:750)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25589)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2299)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2557)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8314)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
2022-11-09 21:47:08.748 30144-30144 AndroidRuntime          com.example.driftdb                  E      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-11-09 21:47:08.779 30144-30144 Process                 com.example.driftdb                  I  Sending signal. PID: 30144 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (30144) for package com.example.driftdb ----------------------------
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (30464) for package com.example.driftdb ----------------------------
```

UPADATE: ADDED SENT AND RECEIVE LAYOUT

received_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/receive_text_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is received Message"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textFontWeight="@integer/material_motion_duration_long_2"
            android:backgroundTint="#4EAEF8"
            android:background="@drawable/searchview_background"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

sent_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sent_text_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="This is sent Message"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
            android:background="@drawable/searchview_background"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />
        

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
THE PROBLEM IN MY CODE WAS THAT THERE WAS ANOTHER RECEIVED_LAYOUT.XML FILE, WHICH WAS BEING CALLED.
I DELETED IT AND IT FIXED EVERYTHING :)

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo ADDED logcat , now can you tell what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you show us the code related to the layout that you're inflating?

Comment: @AlexMamo added both layouts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your bug is in your Messages model.

try initializing your variables on your Messages.

for example:

data class Messages(
messageId: Int = 0,
messageSender: String = "")

thus, they will never appear like null...

sorry for my english jaja

Comment: I have added Message Model , they are all having null check, what to do next ?